# ocr pdf specific reigon

Tags: php, pdf, ocr

I scan field sheets into PDF format and i'm trying to work out how to scan a Specific area of the PDF, i have attached an image below ( the website seen in the picture does what i want ) i have about 100 of these a day and want to do it programmatically.

Any help where to start will be much appreciated as i'm quite out of my depth here

[image: Picture of an example of the region i would want to scan]

I've seen Tesseract and i'm not sure it can scan regions.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to scan a specific area using an image scanner, or are you trying to perform OCR on specific region of an image. You did not even mention your environment. Please provide more information.

Comment: I would prefer to be able to do it in php

Answer (score -1):

I answered a similar question about handwriting zonal OCR just a couple fo days ago.  Includes samples to show the result.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836359/feed-columns-of-handwritten-numbers-on-paper-to-excel?noredirect=1#comment58323681_34836359